# Use the ActiveRecord QueryMethods#from to build a new scope from an existing Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The Rails documentation on the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) has never been very exhaustive, and also the [API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) doesn't help much, so I've never used the **QueryMethods#from** until I've discovered that any existing ActiveRecord Relation can be used as a subquery.

For example, if you have

```
@results= Paper\
  .select( :color, :box_id, 'MAX(size) AS maximum_size' )\
  .group( :color, :box_id )\
  .having( 'AVG(size) > 123' )
```

you can reuse this Relation as an intermediate result table for new queries:

```
Box.from(@results,:previous_scope)\
  .select( :box_id, 'previous_scope.color AS wrap_color')\
  .joins( 'LEFT JOIN items USING (box_id)' )\
  .where( items: {color:'red'} )
```

That's wonderful and saves me from writing nasty `find_by_sql` statements to build complex queries.

Of course it's advisable to define some nice scopes to tidy up the code and avoid duplications:

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :suitable_colors, ->(this,color) {
    from(this,:previous_scope)\
    .select( :box_id, 'previous_scope.color AS wrap_color')\
    .joins( 'LEFT JOIN items USING (box_id)' )\
    .where( items: {color:color} )
  }

end
```

So far so good, this will work if used like `Box.suitable_colors(@results,'green')`.

But it would be a lot better avoiding to pass the Relation as a parameter, so it will be possible to chain it like in `@results.suitable_colors('green')`. I've naively tried different approaches using `from(self,:previous_scope)` but without success (ended up with a `RuntimeError: unsupported: Class` or `ArgumentError: A copy of Box has been removed from the module tree but is still active!`).

The problem is that `@results.is_a? ActiveRecord::Relation` but not `@results.is_a? Box`. Is it any way to define `suitable_colors` as a scope in the Box class?